# JavaFX Label not responding to Mouse EventHandler

Tags: java, events, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

[![enter image description here][1]][1]
I have multiple labels which should be links to multiple Scenes. I've implemented Mouse EventHandlers and the program is compiling fine and running properly except the labels are not responding to clicks. Here's part of the code:

```
 package rootPKG;

 // imports here

 public class LandingController extends Application implements EventHandler<ActionEvent>, Initializable
 {
 @FXML
private ImageView avatarImgView;
@FXML
private Image avatar;
 private Button exit;
@FXML
private Label enterRT;


 @Override
public void handle(ActionEvent event)
{
    if(event.getSource() == addVeh)
    {
        // Instantiating the parent that holds the fxml
        Parent vehParent = null;
        try
        {
            vehParent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Vehicles.fxml"));
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // setting the scene
        Scene vehScene = new Scene(vehParent);

        // setting the stage for the scene
        Stage vehStage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();

        vehStage.setTitle("Create a vehicle");
        vehStage.setScene(vehScene);
        vehStage.setFullScreen(false);
        vehStage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        vehStage.show();
    }


    if(event.getSource() == enterRT)
    {
        enterRT.setOnMouseReleased(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event)
            {
                // Instantiating the parent that holds the fxml
                Parent rTParent = null;
                try
                {
                    rTParent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("RealTime.fxml"));
                }
                catch(IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                // setting the scene
                Scene vehScene = new Scene(rTParent);

                // setting the stage for the scene
                Stage rTStage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();

                rTStage.setTitle("Real Time Mode - Immediate Test");
                rTStage.setScene(vehScene);
                rTStage.setFullScreen(false);
                //rTStage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
                rTStage.show();
            }
        });

 @Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources)
{

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

   }
```

The output from console when I click the enterRT label:

```
      Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:352)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:275)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:388)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:387)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
... 29 more
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent cannot be cast to javafx.event.ActionEvent
at rootPKG.LandingController.handle(LandingController.java:25)
... 39 more
 Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:352)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:275)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:388)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:387)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
... 29 more

 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent cannot be cast to javafx.event.ActionEvent
at rootPKG.LandingController.handle(LandingController.java:25)
... 39 more
```

From the console, I think the error has to do with these lines:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent cannot be cast to javafx.event.ActionEvent
at rootPKG.LandingController.handle(LandingController.java:28)
... 39 more

 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent cannot be cast to javafx.event.ActionEvent
at rootPKG.LandingController.handle(LandingController.java:28)
... 39 more
```

FXML code:

```
 <BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="630.0" prefWidth="1300.0" styleClass="borderpaneStyle" stylesheets="@homelab.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.65" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="rootPKG.LandingController">
 <top>
  <VBox prefHeight="183.0" prefWidth="1300.0" styleClass="universalTranspBg50perc" stylesheets="@homelab.css" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
     <children>
        <HBox prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="1294.0" stylesheets="@homelab.css" VBox.vgrow="NEVER">
           <VBox.margin>
              <Insets bottom="3.0" left="3.0" right="3.0" top="3.0" />
           </VBox.margin>
        </HBox>
        <HBox layoutX="10.0" layoutY="10.0" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
           <children>
              <HBox maxHeight="60.0" maxWidth="60.0" prefHeight="60.0" prefWidth="60.0" styleClass="avatarHBox" stylesheets="@avatar.css">
                 <children>
                    <HBox HBox.hgrow="NEVER">
                       <HBox.margin>
                          <Insets />
                       </HBox.margin>
                       <children>
                          <ImageView fx:id="avatarImgView" fitHeight="60.0" fitWidth="60.0" pickOnBounds="true" smooth="false" styleClass="avatar">
                             <cursor>
                                <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
                             </cursor>
                             <image>
                                <Image url="@appEmblems/homelab%20icon%202.png" />
                             </image>
                          </ImageView>
                       </children>
                    </HBox>
                 </children>
                 <HBox.margin>
                    <Insets left="10.0" right="10.0" />
                 </HBox.margin>
              </HBox>
              <HBox>
                 <children>
                    <Label fx:id="fname" styleClass="username" stylesheets="@avatar.css" text="tapiwa" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
                       <cursor>
                          <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
                       </cursor></Label>
                    <Label fx:id="nick" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="20.0" styleClass="nickname" stylesheets="@avatar.css" text="'tp'" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
                       <HBox.margin>
                          <Insets left="5.0" right="3.0" />
                       </HBox.margin>
                       <cursor>
                          <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
                       </cursor>
                    </Label>
                 </children>
                 <HBox.margin>
                    <Insets right="10.0" />
                 </HBox.margin>
                 <padding>
                    <Insets bottom="10.0" top="10.0" />
                 </padding>
              </HBox>
              <HBox prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="340.0" styleClass="selectedVehWrapper" stylesheets="@homelab.css" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
                 <HBox.margin>
                    <Insets bottom="20.0" left="40.0" right="15.0" top="20.0" />
                 </HBox.margin>
                 <children>
                    <Label fx:id="chosenVeh" styleClass="selectedVeh" stylesheets="@homelab.css" text="2014 Ducati Monster Diesel" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
                       <HBox.margin>
                          <Insets right="5.0" />
                       </HBox.margin>
                       <padding>
                          <Insets bottom="2.0" left="15.0" right="15.0" top="2.0" />
                       </padding>
                       <cursor>
                          <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
                       </cursor>
                    </Label>
                    <Region prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="57.0" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                    <ComboBox fx:id="chooseVeh" opacity="0.86" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="234.0" promptText="click/touch to select vehicle" styleClass="vehListCombo" stylesheets="@homelab.css" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
                       <HBox.margin>
                          <Insets right="5.0" />
                       </HBox.margin>
                       <cursor>
                          <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
                       </cursor>
                    </ComboBox>
                    <Button fx:id="addVeh" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handle" styleClass="buttonAddVeh" stylesheets="@homelab.css" text="add" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
                       <cursor>
                          <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
                       </cursor>
                       <font>
                          <Font name="System Italic" size="12.0" />
                       </font>
                    </Button>
                 </children>
              </HBox>
              <HBox HBox.hgrow="NEVER">
                 <HBox.margin>
                    <Insets />
                 </HBox.margin>
                 <children>
                    <Button fx:id="exit" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handle" styleClass="buttonExit" stylesheets="@homelab.css" text="  EXIT  " />
                 </children>
                 <padding>
                    <Insets bottom="20.0" top="20.0" />
                 </padding>
              </HBox>
              <HBox>
                 <children>
                    <Label fx:id="onlineStatus" onMouseClicked="#handle" styleClass="onlineStatus" stylesheets="@homelab.css" text="    currently offline    ">
                       <effect>
                          <Glow level="1.0" />
                       </effect>
                       <cursor>
                          <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
                       </cursor></Label>
                 </children>
                 <padding>
                    <Insets bottom="5.0" top="25.0" />
                 </padding>
                 <HBox.margin>
                    <Insets left="50.0" right="100.0" />
                 </HBox.margin>
              </HBox>
           </children>
           <VBox.margin>
              <Insets right="75.0" />
           </VBox.margin></HBox>
        <HBox layoutX="10.0" layoutY="93.0" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="1300.0" VBox.vgrow="NEVER" />
        <HBox layoutX="10.0" layoutY="110.0" maxHeight="63.0" prefHeight="63.0" prefWidth="1300.0" VBox.vgrow="NEVER">
           <children>
              <HBox maxWidth="150.0" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="150.0" styleClass="appEmblem" stylesheets="@homelab.css" HBox.hgrow="NEVER">
                 <children>
                    <Label styleClass="appEmblemLabel1" stylesheets="@homelab.css" text="home">
                       <font>
                          <Font size="21.0" />
                       </font>
                       <HBox.margin>
                          <Insets left="3.0" top="5.0" />
                       </HBox.margin>
                       <cursor>
                          <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
                       </cursor>
                    </Label>
                    <Label styleClass="appEmblemLabel2" stylesheets="@homelab.css" text="LAB">
                       <font>
                          <Font size="21.0" />
                       </font>
                       <HBox.margin>
                          <Insets top="5.0" />
                       </HBox.margin>
                       <cursor>
                          <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
                       </cursor>
                    </Label>
                 </children></HBox>
              <HBox styleClass="shortcutLinksFill" stylesheets="@homelab.css" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
                 <children>
                    <TextFlow textAlignment="CENTER" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
                       <children>
                          <Label fx:id="enterRT" onMouseClicked="#handle" onMousePressed="#handle" onMouseReleased="#handle" stylesheets="@homelab.css" text="  Enter Real-Time Mode  " textFill="AQUA">
                             <font>
                                <Font name="Droid Sans" size="15.0" />
                             </font>
                             <styleClass>
                                <String fx:value="shortcutLinksLabelsColor" />
                                <String fx:value="shortcutLinksLabelsfont" />
                             </styleClass>
                             <cursor>
                                <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
                             </cursor>
                             <padding>
                                <Insets left="20.0" right="20.0" />
                             </padding>
                          </Label>
                          <Label fx:id="Notif" stylesheets="@homelab.css" text="  Notifications  " textFill="AQUA">
                             <font>
                                <Font name="Droid Sans" size="15.0" />
                             </font>
                             <styleClass>
                                <String fx:value="shortcutLinksLabelsColor" />
                                <String fx:value="shortcutLinksLabelsfont" />
                             </styleClass>
                             <cursor>
                                <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
                             </cursor>
                             <padding>
                                <Insets left="20.0" right="20.0" />
                             </padding>
                          </Label>
                          <Label fx:id="profile" stylesheets="@homelab.css" text="  Profile  " textFill="AQUA">
                             <font>
                                <Font name="Droid Sans" size="15.0" />
                             </font>
                             <styleClass>
                                <String fx:value="shortcutLinksLabelsColor" />
                                <String fx:value="shortcutLinksLabelsfont" />
                             </styleClass>
                             <cursor>
                                <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
                             </cursor>
                             <padding>
                                <Insets left="20.0" right="20.0" />
                             </padding>
                          </Label>
                          <Label fx:id="prefs" stylesheets="@homelab.css" text="  Preferences  " textFill="AQUA">
                             <font>
                                <Font name="Droid Sans" size="15.0" />
                             </font>
                             <styleClass>
                                <String fx:value="shortcutLinksLabelsColor" />
                                <String fx:value="shortcutLinksLabelsfont" />
                             </styleClass>
                             <cursor>
                                <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
                             </cursor>
                             <padding>
                                <Insets left="20.0" right="20.0" />
                             </padding>
                          </Label>
                          <Label fx:id="help" stylesheets="@homelab.css" text="  Help  " textFill="AQUA">
                             <font>
                                <Font name="Droid Sans" size="15.0" />
                             </font>
                             <styleClass>
                                <String fx:value="shortcutLinksLabelsColor" />
                                <String fx:value="shortcutLinksLabelsfont" />
                             </styleClass>
                             <cursor>
                                <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
                             </cursor>
                             <padding>
                                <Insets left="20.0" right="20.0" />
                             </padding>
                          </Label>
                       </children>
                    </TextFlow>
                 </children>
                 <padding>
                    <Insets bottom="10.0" top="10.0" />
                 </padding>
              </HBox>
```

Left out some code due to body limit but the crucial code is included.

Comment: Can you show more context and also identify the line that is throwing the exception? It looks like all the code you posted is part of an event handler (since you refer to `event.getSource()`), so it seems strange that you are registering one event handler in the process of handling another.

Comment: @James_D, I've added more relevant code... Tell me if I've left out anything else..Thanks!

Comment: There is nowhere in the code you posted where you register this object as an event handler for something. Somewhere you must be doing `someNode.setOnAction(this)` or something equivalent. How is the `handle()` method even getting invoked? And you still didn't say which line is throwing the exception.

Comment: The IDE is not showing which line, the only output I'm getting from the console is what I've typed above. I'm not a very experienced programmer  but what I did was take similar code I used for a button (which works) and used it for the Label where I typed:         enterRT.setOnMouseReleased(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event)

Comment: I added linked handle method in the FXML file in the code section - using Scene Builder.

Comment: The stack trace tells you which line.

Comment: I found this line in the console after I clicked the Label:    Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent cannot be cast to javafx.event.ActionEvent
 at rootPKG.LandingController.handle(LandingController.java:28)

Comment: Well I think I can guess which line is line 28, but it would be nice if you could be bothered to tell everyone. You should also post your actual FXML code instead of a screenshot of SceneBuilder.

Comment: Thanks! Let me do that right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the wrong event type as a parameter to your `handle` method. Mouse pressed and mouse released events generate `MouseEvent`s, not `ActionEvent`s. Hence you get the class cast exception, because when the handler created by the FXML loader passes the event object (a `MouseEvent`) to the method, it tries to cast it to an `ActionEvent`.

In general, though, you have fundamentally misunderstood how event handling in a controller class is set up. There is no need for your controller to implement `EventHandler`. When the FXML loader loads the fxml file, it will create the necessary event handlers for you, whose `handle` methods invoke the methods you specify in the fxml, and it will register those handlers with the nodes you define. So all you need to do is to write a method to handle the "mouse pressed" event, and a method to handle the "mouse released" event, and specify those methods in the fxml. The handler methods you specify can have any name, and can either have zero parameters, or can have a single parameter for the appropriate event type (i.e. `MouseEvent` in this case). So your controller should look like:

```
public class LandingController extends Application implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private ImageView avatarImgView;
    @FXML
    private Image avatar;
    @FXML
    private Button exit;
    @FXML
    private Label enterRT;

    @FXML
    private void handleMousePress(MouseEvent event) {
        // code in this method is executed when the mouse is pressed
        // on a node with onMousePressed="#handleMousePress"
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleMouseRelease(MouseEvent event) {
        // code in this method is executed when the mouse is released
        // on a node with onMousePressed="#handleMouseRelease"
    }

    @FXML
    private void add(ActionEvent event) {
        // code in this method is executed when an action event
        // occurs on a node with onAction="#add"
    }


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    }

}
```

and now for the label(s) of interest, simply specify `onMousePress="#handleMousePress"` and `onMouseRelease="handleMouseRelease"` in the FXML file, or select the methods in the appropriate boxes in Scene Builder. Again, the `FXMLLoader` takes care of implementing `EventHandler` and registering the handlers for you, there is no need (and it's incorrect) to do this yourself.

Comment: Ohhhhh Yes! Worked! Thanks a lot. Learnt a lot - i'll change my code right away. Thanks a lot! If you have some links to good tutorials please provide hook me up with a link. :)

Comment: A lot of people seem to like [this tutorial](http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/)

Comment: I'll make use of it. Thank you!